# Check How Close UITouch Is To A UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIImageView that is being spawned in a random position but is hidden. I have also set up a UITouch that prints an NSLog stating the coordinates of the touch. How can I check how close the tap was to the randomly spawned UIImageView?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have a pointer to the UIImageView

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
CGRect imageViewRect = [imageView frame];
double xdiff = touchLocation.x - imageViewRect.origin.x + imageViewRect.size.width/2;
double ydiff = touchLocation.y - imageViewRect.origin.y + imageViewRect.size.height/2;
double distance = sqrt(xdiff*xdiff+ydiff*ydiff);
NSLog("Distance=%ld", distance);
```